# CSS responsive nav list burger style in mobile view?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my code I am trying to achieve simular style of navbar but not with bootstrap. Responsive list when resized the list stacks on top like this:

[image]

I have tried using; `@media screen and (min-width: 480px)` but it did not work any suggestions?

This should only be when in mobile view and when in desktop view it should stay to the left as it is.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 25%;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="htmll logo" align="middle"></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Länk 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Länk 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Länk 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Länk 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Innehåll</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All styles defined in CSS will be valid for the entire document.
Which means you only need to define the different states inside

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { /* here */ }
```

but make sure to add `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { /* here */ }` to the end of your CSS

Also note that I changed `min-width` to `max-width`

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

img {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;

}

.container{

  margin-left:25%;
  padding:1px 16px;
  height:1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
    
    ul {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="htmll logo" align="middle"></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Länk 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Länk 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Länk 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Länk 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Innehåll</h1>

</div>
```

Here is a link to jsfiddle so you can resize the view area and see how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ctvvf6be/

Comment: Thank you worked just fine and thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

For Mobile View Only, following media query will work fine,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    ...
}
```